# Get event object in a directly declared HTML event tag

Tags: javascript, html, events

So let's say I have an input element like this:

```
<input type="text" id="123">
```

Now if I where to add an event listener for keydown, I could do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("123").onkeydown = function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
};
```

But if I would want to do it directly inside the HTML, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="123" onkeydown="console.log(e.keyCode);">
```

I would get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

How do I capture the `e` variable if I would want to set the event directly inside the HTML document?

Comment: What's wrong with the first option?

Comment: @Erik-JanWestendorp It's the fact that it makes my code much clearer, since I would only need one line of code for that part.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar What? xD

Comment: @Erik-JanWestendorp Here is my original code: `onkeypress="/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)) && e.preventDefault()"`

Comment: @Murplyx The following should also work, `onkeydown=javscript:console.log(event.keyCode);`

Comment: @Anthony `javascript:` is excess. It's used in `href`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the *window.event* object.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="123" onkeydown="console.log(window.event.keyCode);">
```

(And in fact, you can even omit `window`.)

Comment: Yeah, that's a perfect answer.

Comment: And since it's window, I could just write `event.keyCode` instead of `window.event.keyCode`?

Comment: good call @nicael... I figured I'd be more verbose in my answer but both work!!